# Must a Suslin line be star countable?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

> 1. **A Suslin line is defined to be a nonseparable ccc linearly
>      ordered space.**
> 2. **A topological space $X$ is said to be star countable if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a countable subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \operatorname{St}(K,\mathscr{U})$.**

My question is this:

Must a Suslin line be star countable?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because a ccc ordered space is Lindelöf (classic fact; a Suslin line is an example of an ordered L-space: regular, hereditarily Lindelöf but not separable) and all Lindelöf spaces are star countable (trivial; pick a countable subcover and a point from each member).